# Expectation Value of the Product of a Time integral and a Ito Integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider a stochastic process $X_t$
\begin{equation}
dX_t = a(X_t)dt + \sigma dW_t
\end{equation}
where $W_t$ is a Wiener Process.

I know the expectation value of the product of two stochastic integrals can be written as the expectation value of a time integral.

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\Big[\Big( \int^{\tau}_0 F(X_t) dW_t \Big) \cdot \Big(\int^{\tau}_0 G(X_t) dW_t \Big) \Big] = \mathbb{E}\Big[\int^{\tau}_0 F(X_t)\cdot G(X_t) dt \Big]
\end{equation}

I am trying to evaluate the following expectation value of the product of a time integral and a stochastic integral:

\begin{equation}
C(\tau) = \mathbb{E}\Big[\Big( \int^{\tau}_0 f(X_t) dt \Big) \cdot \Big(\int^{\tau}_0 g(X_t) dW_t \Big) \Big]
\end{equation}
where $f(X_t)$ and $g(X_t)$ are arbitrary functions of $X_t$, and the stochastic integral is interpreted as an Ito integral.

Is it possible to write $C(\tau)$ as an expectation value of a time integral or a double time integral?
\begin{equation}
C(\tau) = \mathbb{E}\Big[ \int^{\tau}_0 A(X_t) dt \Big] \quad \textrm{or} \quad \mathbb{E}\Big[\int^{\tau}_0 \int^{\alpha(t)}_0 A(X_t) \cdot B(X_s) ds dt \Big]
\end{equation}

Comment: You can adapt the proof for Itô's isometry formula to your case and you'll see that $C(\tau) = 0$.

Comment: I dont think above is true $C(\tau)$ cannot be $0$ as $X_t$  depends on $dW_t$ if you write it down as a limit using the definition of the Ito integral and apply DCT only for some ranges $s<t$ (use $s$ as the index of the first integral $t$ as the index of the second)  would you get $0$, furthermore if it were $0$ it would imply the covariance between these two integrals is $0$ which seems quite unlikely. You should maybe remove that comment, I think its incomplete, very confusing and potentially wrong (hard to verify).